# next + custom server + typescript + npx = Error

Tags: typescript, next.js, npx

If I create an app with

- `npx create-next-app --typescript example-app`
- Create server.ts

  - Insert into server.ts code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-js-custom-server/
  - Change `require()` to `import`
  - Add `//@ts-nocheck` to the top of `server.ts`
- tsconfig.json

  - Change "target" to `"target": "ESNext",`
- package.json

  - Change "dev" script to `"dev": "npx tsx server.ts",`

When I tried to run `npm run dev` I get the following error

```
TypeError: Unexpected response from worker: undefined
at ChildProcessWorker._onMessage (.......\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:12492)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "example-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx tsx server.ts",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.6.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**server.ts**

```
//@ts-nocheck
// const next = require('next')
// const http = require('http')
import { createServer } from "http";
import next from "next";

const app = next({dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'})

app.prepare().then(() => {
const server = createServer((req, res) => {
// Handle API routes
if (req.url.startsWith('/api')) {
    // Your API handling logic here
} else {
    // Handle Next.js routes
    return app.getRequestHandler()(req, res)
}
})
server.listen(3000, (err) => {
if (err) throw err
console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've stop upon the same problem atm. Still no solution in regards of `tsx`. I've also tried `ts-node-dev` with the same issue.

If you just want to run the server process as a typescript file you can try `ts-node`

P.S.

Don't do Add //@ts-nocheck to the top of server.ts

Here is whats working for me:

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json server.ts",
    "build:client": "next build",
    "build:server": "tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "build": "pnpm build:server && pnpm build:client",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

```json
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "$/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "plugins": [{ "name": "next" }]
  },
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.cjs",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.cjs",
    "**/*.mjs",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "out"]
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.server.json

{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["server.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "out"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  }
}
```